# Photospace Gallerific wordpress responsive vertical gallery thumbnails media queries javascript css?

Tags: css, plugins, responsive-design, galleriffic

I'd like to make my gallery http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photospace-responsive/ be responsive with a vertical layout changing into a horizontal one when the browser is scaled down for mobile.

Please can you tell me how I can make it revert when the screen size is smaller to the gallery being on top?

See my test page
http://brightmist.co.uk/gallery/

I've even tried media queries

```
    .photospace_res .gal_content {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.photospace_res .thumbs_wrap2 {
    float: left;
    min-height: 800px;
    width: 20%;
}
@media all and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .photospace_res .gal_content {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .photospace_res .thumbs_wrap2 {
        float: none;
        min-height: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help
Judi

Answer (score 0):

Yay I fixed it and added a few extra styles

```
    .photospace_res .gal_content {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.photospace_res .thumbs_wrap2 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.photospace_res {
    margin: 0;
}

.photospace_res .ss-controls {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .photospace_res .gal_content {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .photospace_res .thumbs_wrap2 {
        float: none;
        min-height: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```